# How can I hide a part of an reflection in Cycles

Tags: reflection

I want to hide the red reflection as shown in the image below. I achieved this in Eevee, and I want to do it in Cycles because it looks more realistic in Cycles. I've tried adjusting light path settings like glossy and diffuse, as well as all blend modes and screen space reflections, but it's not working.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DDNB0hsYgwc599h7QR7H5V7gyV2DL4ls/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello what causes the red reflection? Maybe share your file? Don't forget to pack your images

Comment: We really can't help you if we're not given any clue about red things in your scene.. are you saying there are none, and this is a complete mystery?

Comment: check link @moonboots

Comment: you have an ColorRamp with orange colors plugged into the Base Color of your Principled BSDF, so it seems normal that the reflection becomes redish?

Comment: Is it possible to turn off the reflection setting so that it does not reflect like in the upper image @moonboots

Comment: its only reflecting in cycle, in eevee look normal

Comment: Yes because in Eevee by default you won't have any reflection of the objects that are in the scene

Answer (score 5):

[image]

If you are looking how to eliminate reflection of object in its surface at all like in Eevee try this ...

[image]
[image]

... or you can go to *Object Properties > Visibility > Ray Visibility* and uncheck **Glossy**.

[image]

If you need to uncheck *Glossy* for more objects at once select all participating objects and uncheck *Glossy*. By hovering over checkbox right click and choose from contextual menu **Copy to Selected**.

[image]

---

*Note: Keep in mind ... by "cropping" the real behaviour of path traycing from render you devaluate realism of Cycles, that you choose for. So you lost all benefits of realism and just increase a render time :)*

Comment: You are probably experiencing reflection of other objects ...  so do the same for light object ... or  uncheck Glossy in Object Properties > Visibility > Ray Visibility ... btw I just noticed you can plug Reflection ray directly to Mix Factor (World shader is still reflecting).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the *Is Glossy Ray* output of an *Input > Light Path* as factor between your current material and a *Glossy* that is white:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, buddy, it was greatly helpful @moonboots